# Python - How to convert dictionary alike string to dictionary

Tags: python

I have a string as below

```
"{"V":1,"Batch":10001,"File":"abc.csv","ContactorID":"A001"}"
```

How can I actually convert this string to a dictionary? The string originate from a txt file

Comment: [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html?highlight=json%20loads#json.loads)

Comment: [`ast.literal_eval(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) will also work. Just depends what you're doing. This is useful if you have a column of dict strings in a dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the json module. You can either open the file and use `json.load(file)` or include the text as a string in your program and do `json.loads(text)`. For example:

```
import json

with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    dict_from_file = json.load(file)
```

or

```
import json

text = '{"V":1,"Batch":10001,"File":"abc.csv","ContactorID":"A001"}'

dict_from_text = json.loads(text)
```

For more info see https://realpython.com/python-json/.